# For a convex shape can we show small translation and rotations will keep it within an open set?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Define a convex shape $C(r, q)$, where $r$ represents the position of the convex shape and $q$ represents the orientation of the convex shape. Let $V$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ where $C \subseteq V$. Can we show that there exists an open set $U$, with $(r, q) \in U$, such that $C(\bar{r}, \bar{q}) \subseteq V$ for any $(\bar{r}, \bar{q}) \in U$.

The type of convex shape I have in mind are like polygons and ellipsoids, and $C(r, q)$ is the convex set that is both the interior and the surface of the convex shapes in mind. These convex sets are compact, which I think from the Heince-Borel Theorem implies that they are also closed and bounded.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You probably need some sort of boundedness/compactness. In $R^2$, in the first quadrant, think about the convex set $\{xy\gt1\}$, and the containing open set being the interior of the first quadrant. Any small movement down will move the convex set below the x axis.

Comment: You want to assume $C$ is compact, I think.   Convexity is irrelevant.

Comment: The type of convex shapes I have in mind are polygons and ellipsoids. Does this clarification help?

Comment: Take the line $y=0$ and the open set $|y|<1$ in the plane. Any rotation of the (convex) line will take it 'outside' the open set. You need boundedness.

Comment: I changed the assumption to closed and bounded sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the compact set $C$ is a subset of the open set $V$. Then each point of $c$ has an open neighborhood in $V$. Compactness implies that a finite subset of those neighborhoods covers $C$. Then a small change in position stays in that finite cover.

Comment: I guess this directly extends to the case of small rotations and small translations? Also do you mean a finite subset of the **union** of those neighborhoods?

Comment: Yes - since rotations and translations are the only ways to change the position. To say there's a finite cover means that the union of finitely many of the neighborhoods covers (i.e. includes as a subset) $C$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the help!